# Excel UserForm: accessing textBoxes by index

Tags: excel, userform

I have a large userForm with a lot of textBoxes on it.  Some of the textBoxes have simple names like textBox1, textBox2...textBox30.  I want to be able to access them by saying something like:

for i = 1 to 30
Control("textBox" & i) = "stuff"
next i

I know I could loop through all of the controls on the page and stop everytime there is a textBox but that does not work for my purposes.  I also want to be able to call the textBoxes by name using this method.

Answer (score 0):

wait I think this actually works if I change "Control" to "Controls"